# How validate Model with before_filter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I want to make the validation of the Model and move it to `before_filter`. How in the filter can be assigned to the standard validators presence, etc.?

Validation example:

```
validates :project_id, :date, :user_id, :time_from, presence: true
validates :time_from, :format => { with: /[0-2]?[0-9]:[0-5][0-9]/ }
validates :time_to, :format => { with: /[0-2]?[0-9]:[0-5][0-9]/ }, :allow_blank => true
validates :team, presence: true
validate :time_from_lt_time_to
validate :only_current_month
```

UPD:
I found a [solution](https://coderwall.com/p/ea5vtw/validating-rest-queries-with-rails)! thanks for the help

In my case I will need to make

```
before_filter :validate_params, :except => [:create, :update]
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Can you be more specific, please?

Comment: @Coolness I want to move all the validation of the model to the controller. The model is very congested. This makes it difficult to test. Validation needs to be served for only two methods create and update.

Comment: This is unwise. Validation is kept with the model for lots of good reasons that this margin is too small to contain. If you want to physically reduce the size of your model, there are other ways of doing this (eg concerns or even just plain ruby modules). But validations should be done at the model-level.

Comment: You're testing it wrong... Model validations are extremely simple to test. Setting up a HTTP request to trigger a specific condition in the controller is much harder.